# Android Studio Settings Repository Sync Error "git-upload-pack not permitted"

Tags: git, android-studio

I use android studio's settngs repository to sync my settings across devices. Recently, whenever I try to sync settings I encounter the following error

```
https://github.com/sushmoyr/Android-studio-settings.git: git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://github.com/sushmoyr/Android-studio-settings.git/'
```

It used to work perfectly until a few days ago. I have signed in with a personal access token that have necessary permissions. I can't find any solutions.

Comment: May be caused by outdate github token, if expired, create new one and replace

Comment: I generated new token with necessary permissions. But still not working.